# Problem with usercontrols in Umbraco

Tags: user-controls, umbraco

I have developed a usercontrol that I would like to embed in Umbraco.  The process seems straightforward, but I may be trying something that can't be done.

My usercontrol is dependent on several other usercontrols.  When I try to Browse Properties in the "main" usercontrol I get the error below.

I have copied all the .ascx files to the usercontrols folder and the assembly is in the bin directory.  Is it possible to host a "composite" usercontrol in Umbraco that depends on and contains other usercontrols?

> System.Web.HttpParseException: The file '/ucLogin.ascx' does not exist. ---> System.Web.HttpParseException: The file '/ucLogin.ascx' does not exist. ---> System.Web.HttpException: The file '/ucLogin.ascx' does not exist. at System.Web.UI.Util.CheckVirtualFileExists(VirtualPath virtualPath) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) at System.Web.UI.BaseTemplateParser.GetReferencedType(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean allowNoCompile) at System.Web.UI.BaseTemplateParser.GetUserControlType(VirtualPath virtualPath) at System.Web.UI.MainTagNameToTypeMapper.ProcessUserControlRegistration(UserControlRegisterEntry ucRegisterEntry) at System.Web.UI.BaseTemplateParser.ProcessDirective(String directiveName, IDictionary directive) at System.Web.UI.TemplateControlParser.ProcessDirective(String directiveName, IDictionary directive) at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding fileEncoding) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessException(Exception ex) at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding fileEncoding) at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding) at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseReader(StreamReader reader, VirtualPath virtualPath) at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseFile(String physicalPath, VirtualPath virtualPath) at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseInternal() at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.Parse() at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.Parse(ICollection referencedAssemblies, VirtualPath virtualPath) at System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType() at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider buildProvider) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders() at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) at System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.LoadControl(VirtualPath virtualPath) at System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.LoadControl(String virtualPath) at umbraco.developer.assemblyBrowser.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usercontrol reference to other controls via the rootpath. Can you change the reference /ucLogin.ascx to ucLogin.ascx and see what happens.

Hope it helps you,

Richard

Comment: That was it... I had the reference with ~/ in the register directive... thanks so much, feeling very silly right now!